# Javascript - Counting array elements by reduce method until specific value occurs doesn't give a correct output

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => arr.reduce((total)=>(num==0 ? total : total+num), 0) 
console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

Please check how can I make it work. Did some mistake but don't know what exactly. Output is a function instead of a result.

Comment: What is `x`? You've never defined that variable.

Comment: So now, if you call `sum` and pass `0` as the second parameter, you'd not count anything...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Got it, but how else can I count until specific value (2nd argument) occurs ? @VLAZ

Comment: @Nick it's 11. the sum of the numbers before argument 0 occurs in array.

Comment: @ElMuchacho use the second argument of `reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is awkward to do in `.reduce` because it goes through the *entire* array. If we do a naive implementation you can see the problem:

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => arr.reduce((total, x)=>(num==x ? total : total+x), 0) 
console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

We now make the check correctly - `num==x` will return `true` when `x` is zero (the value of `num`). However, the result is wrong because this only returns `true` *once* but any other iteration it's still `true`. And here is the same thing with more logging that describes each step of the process:

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => arr.reduce((total, x)=> {
  const boolCheck = num==x;
  const result = boolCheck ? total : total+x;
  console.log(
`total: ${total}
num: ${num}
x: ${x}
boolCheck: ${boolCheck}
result: ${result}`);

    return result;
  }, 0) 
console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

So, you need to add some flag that persists between iterations, so it doesn't get lost.

One option is to have an external flag that you change within the `reduce` callback:

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => {
  let finished = false;
  return arr.reduce((total, x) => {
    if(x === num)
      finished = true;
      
    return finished ? total : total+x;
  }, 0)
}
console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

Alternatively, you can have that flag internal to the `reduce` callback and pass it around between calls. It works the same way in the end but makes the callback function pure. At the cost of some unorthodox construct:

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => {
  return arr.reduce(({total, finished}, x) => {
    if(x === num)
      finished = true;

    total = finished ? total : total+x;

    return {total, finished};
  }, {total: 0, finished: false})
  .total
}
console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

If you want to use `reduce` but you're OK with using other methods, then you can use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the first instance of a value and [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the array that contains any value up to the target value:

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => {
  const endIndex = arr.indexOf(num);
  
  return arr.slice(0, endIndex)
    .reduce((total, x)=> total+x, 0)
}
console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

Or in as one chained expression:

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => arr
  .slice(0, arr.indexOf(num))
  .reduce((total, x)=> total+x, 0);

console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

Other libraries may have a `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` operation which is even closer to what you want - it gets you an array *from* the beginning *up to* a given value or condition. You can then reduce the result of that.

Here is an example of this using [`Lodash#takeWhile`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#takeWhile)

By using chaining here, Lodash will do lazy evaluation, so it will only go through the array once, instead of scanning once to find the end index and going through the array again to sum it.

```js
const arr = [5,6,0,7,8];
const sum = (arr,num) => _(arr)
  .takeWhile(x => x !== num)
  .reduce((total, x)=>total+x, 0)

console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As a note, if you *are* using Lodash, then you may as well use [`_.sum()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sum). I didn't above just to illustrate how a generic `takeUntil`/`takeWhile` looks.

```js
const arr = [5, 6, 0, 7, 8];
const sum = (arr, num) => _(arr)
  .takeWhile(x => x !== num)
  .sum()

console.log(sum(arr, 0))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification! Total newbie, was thinking that it would be less code if making it by reduce, but it seems like it's the same as you do it by 'for loops':)))

Comment: You can also slice the array. That would avoid having a very complex `reduce` logic. I've added a note on that.

Comment: Omg, man, so many options to do - you're the boss! thank you again!

Comment: The only problem is that I have a hard time with understanding the code with "slice" method

Comment: `.slice` takes a portion of the array *from* an index, *to* another index. The first argument is `0`, so it starts from the beginning. The second argument is (effectively) the result of  `.indexOf(0)` which is the position of the first zero in the array. So, it's like a manual implementation of `takeUntil` functionality where you get the portion of the array from the beginning until the first zero.

Comment: thank you so much, Vlaz! I got the idea! Brilliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to stop summing values part way through the array, this might be most simply implemented using a `for` loop:

```js
const arr = [5, 6, 0, 7, 8];
const num = 0;

let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == num) break;
  sum += arr[i];
}
console.log(sum);
```

If you want to use `reduce`, you need to keep a flag that says whether you have seen the `num` value so you can stop adding values from the array:

```js
const arr = [5, 6, 0, 7, 8];

const sum = (arr, num) => {
  let seen = false;
  return arr.reduce((c, v) => {
    if (seen || v == num) {
      seen = true;
      return c;
    }
    return c + v;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(sum(arr, 0));
console.log(sum(arr, 8));
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, but I want to know how make it by reduce.

Comment: @ElMuchacho see my edit, I've added an alternate piece of code using `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

call it as follows:

```
console.log(sum(arr, 0)());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis to execute the function `()`

```
sum(arr, 0)
```

Without parenthesis you store a reference to the function in the variable